# find child item script (conversion from powershell)

Tags: python-2.7, file, powershell, finder

I have to search rather large file windows file shares for faxes sent and received from my company.  I am new to Python 2.7 but i did find this powershell find-child-item script which works semi-decently.

The script allows me to input a search path, and then search for keyterms or phrases.  (this is very useful when i'm searching a folder that could contain 400k to 1 million fax files that all have sender/ receiver numbers in their file name.

But the script runs slow, and i dont care much for powershell.  can anyone help me convert this?

Thanks!

```
#>
"`n"
write-Host "---------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$filePath = Read-Host "Please Enter File Path to Search"
write-Host "---------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
$fileName = Read-Host "Please Enter File Name to Search"
write-Host "---------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
"`n"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and
                   ( $_.Name -like "*$fileName*") } |
    Select-Object Name,Directory |
    Format-Table -AutoSize *

write-Host "------------END of Result--------------------" -ForegroundColor Magenta

pause

# end of the script
```

Comment: It runs slowly because you're not using `-Filter` or `-File` on `Get-ChildItem`.  Learn the mantra: Filter left, format right.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Some people are not using the latest PowerShell though. So they might not be able to use `-Filter` or `-File` in their commands.

Comment: @ShawnEsterman `-Filter` has existed since v1.0.  `-File` was introduced in v3.0.

Answer (score -1):

In PowerShell, with significant improvements:

```
#Requires -Version 3
Write-Host "---------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor 'Yellow'
$filePath = Read-Host "Please Enter File Path to Search"
Write-Host "---------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor 'Green'
$fileName = Read-Host "Please Enter File Name to Search"
Write-Host "---------------------------------------------`r`n" -ForegroundColor 'Yellow'

$Params = @{
    Path = $filePath
    Filter = "*$fileName*"
    File = $True
    Recurse = $True
    Force = $True #not sure why you included this. It forces finding hidden folders
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
}
Get-ChildItem @Params |
    Select-Object -Property @('Name','Directory') |
    Format-Table -Property '*' -AutoSize

Write-Host '------------END of Result--------------------' -ForegroundColor 'Magenta'

Pause
```

Comment: i supposed i need to get more familiar with python syntax.  every time i run in python i'm getting syntax errors.

Comment: @bdub2841 If you're not aiming for cross-compatibility, there's little reason to do this in `py`